# How to make provider assume_role block conditional

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a `provider` block which I want to give an `assume_role` property but only if it is not running on my local machine.

I have defined a variable `islocal` in all the environment `.tfvars` files, with only the local file having the value `true`.

This is the `provider` block:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region1
    profile = var.islocal == true ? "default" : null # ONLY USED LOCALLY
    
    assume_role {       # NOT TO BE USED LOCALLY
        role_arn = var.terraform_execution_role
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. If I set the `role_arn` property to `null` does this make the `assume_role` block ineffective? (ie: the same as not being there)
2. If the `assume_role` block does have an impact, even when the `role_arn` value is `null`, how can I completely remove it when `var.islocal` is `true`?

I have considered a dynamic block but I'm not sure how to structure it.

Comment: Not sure about the first question - the second one could be achieved with a `dynamic` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) in your provider:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region1
    profile = var.islocal == true ? "default" : null # ONLY USED LOCALLY
    
  dynamic "assume_role" {    
    for_each = var.islocal == true ? [] : [1]  
    content {      
        role_arn = var.terraform_execution_role
    }  
  }
}
```