# How to make a terraform resource block conditional

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.14.7

I have a `aws_acm_certificate` which I would like to avoid when running my `tf` locally (because I don't want to acquire a domain name, etc). I also don't want to comment out all the involved code when running locally. Most of my other blocks ([such as a provider's `assume_role`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473337/how-to-make-provider-assume-role-block-conditional)) have been able to be excluded when running locally. How can I do this with a complete resource?

I was expecting to be able to set the `count` value to a variable in an environment `tfvars` file:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  count = var.islocal == true ? 0 : 1

  domain_name       = "www.mysite.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

This leads to other problems, like the need to reference that resource in other place. For example, outputting the result of the resource becomes problematic:

```
output "acm_cert_domain_validation_options" {
  description = "definition of aws certificate requested for cloudfront"
  value = aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].domain_validation_options
}
```

In this case, if the `count` var is `0` the output will fail on `plan` and I can't use the same approach there because `count` is not supported by `output`.

Other than simply not outputting the value, is there a way to conditional exclude entire blocks safely?

Comment: It seems this is the correct approach (well, the best I can find). For the output you can't omit it, and that is probably correct, but you can return nothing in local env. Something like `value = var.islocal ? null : aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].domain_validation_options`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be tricky depending on how many resources are inter-depedent, but something that could work in your case is the use of `-target` when you run your plan locally.

Imagine the following terraform code with an S3 and ACM certificate, and you only want to execute locally the S3 code and avoid the ACM:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_bucket" {
  bucket_prefix = "whatever-"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {

  domain_name       = "www.mysite.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}


output "acm_cert_domain_validation_options" {
  description = "definition of aws certificate requested for cloudfront"
  value = aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].domain_validation_options
}
```

Then I could run:

```
terraform plan -target=aws_s3_bucket.my_s3_bucket
```

In that way terraform will avoid to run the ACM code (including the outputs).
You can add many targets:

```
terraform plan -target=aws_s3_bucket.my_s3_bucket -target=aws_s3_bucket.my_s3_bucket_2
```

I always try keep the terraform code as clear as possible by avoiding using counters if they are not strictly necessary, otherwise the terraform code could become difficult to follow and maintain.